# Drop Down Selection True or False

Tags: php

I have a dropdown box which has true or false for options.  If true is selected, I want a selected picture to be displayed.  If false is selected, I want a different picture to be displayed

Here is my code so far:

```
<form>
   <select name="Picture">
      <option value= <?php $Test = True ?>"True">True</option>
      <option value=<?php $Test = False ?>"False">False</option>

      <?php
         if ($Test == "True")
            echo "<img src = '../Images/Worked.jpg'>";
         else 
            echo "<img src = '../Images/DidntWork.jpg'>";
      ?>
   </select>
</form>
```

All I seem to get is the drop down menu but no images.  Also I'm not sure that the true/false selector is correct.

Comment: This would be much more easily achieved with javascript

Comment: You don't reload the page so the image will not change. Also you are not allowed to use `<img>` in a `<select>`

Comment: I agree but its I'm just playing around with PHP for the moment. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: You have *several* fundamental misunderstandings of how HTML, Javascript, and server-side PHP interact and co-operate. It would do you well to learn each from the bottom-up, as it isn't clear you have a grasp on any of them.

Comment: @Kie21 when I said "more easily achieved with javascript" I actually meant "impossible to do without javascript". There are also numerous issues with the PHP. If you are attempting to learn PHP, perhaps you should try some more simple tasks first :)

Comment: @rwacarter Ahh see thanks for the info :) Ill add some javascript in with it all.

Comment: Slight annoyed at the downvote. I thought this site was a place to improve code and for learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.

First, `<?php $Test = True ?>`.  This *sets* `$Test`.  You need to do `==` to compare (like you do later on).

Second, you *cannot* have `<img>` tags as children of a `<select>`.  You'll need to place them outside of the `<select>`.

Third, you use the `selected` attribute to mark which `<option>` should be selected.

```
<form>
    <select name="Picture">
        <option <?=$Test == "True" ? 'selected' : ''?> value="True">True</option>
        <option <?=$Test == "False" ? 'selected' : ''?> value="False">False</option>
    </select>

    <?php
    if ($Test == "True"){
        echo "<img src = \"../Images/Worked.jpg\">";
    }
    else {
        echo "<img src = \"../Images/DidntWork.jpg\">";
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Note: This will only display the image when the page is loaded.  If you want it to change when the `<select>` is changed, you'll need to use JavaScript (or reload the page after you save the value).

Comment: _Edit: Question was edited according to my comment. Thanks._ This won't work because the page is not reloading - the selection will have no effect

Comment: @Wavemaster: I added a note about that to the bottom the answer.